# Reference a common setter in property write

Tags: arrays, delphi, setter

Could I reference a common setter `_setTerm` in properties' `write` accessor without writing individual setter methods `_setTerm1`, `_setTerm2`, `_setTerm3`?

```
TAdder = class(TCalculatorComponent)
private
  _terms: array[1..10] of OleVariant;
  procedure _setTerm(const i: Integer; const Value: OleVariant);
  procedure _setTerm1(const Value: OleVariant);
  procedure _setTerm2(const Value: OleVariant);
  procedure _setTerm3(const Value: OleVariant);
  .......
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  property Term1: OleVariant read _terms[1] write _setTerm1;
  property Term2: OleVariant read _terms[2] write _setTerm2;
  property Term3: OleVariant read _terms[3] write _setTerm3;
  .......
end;

implementation

procedure TAdder._setTerm(const i: Integer; const Value: OleVariant);
begin
  _terms[i] := TVarConv.NullableFloat(Value);
  _calculate();
end;

procedure TAdder._setTerm1(const Value: OleVariant);
begin
  _setTerm(1, Value);
end;

procedure TAdder._setTerm2(const Value: OleVariant);
begin
  _setTerm(2, Value);
end;

procedure TAdder._setTerm3(const Value: OleVariant);
begin
  _setTerm(3, Value);
end;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution #1

```
type
  TAdder = class
  private
    _terms: array[1..10] of OleVariant;
    procedure _setTerm(const i: Integer; const Value: OleVariant);
    function _getTerm(const Index: Integer): OleVariant;
public
  property Term1: OleVariant index 1 read _getTerm write _SetTerm;
  property Term2: OleVariant index 2 read _getTerm write _SetTerm;
  property Term3: OleVariant index 3 read _getTerm write _SetTerm;
end;

function TAdder._getTerm(const Index: Integer): OleVariant;
begin
  Result := _terms[i];
end;

procedure TAdder._setTerm(const i: Integer; const Value: OleVariant);
begin
  _terms[i] := TVarConv.NullableFloat(Value);
  _calculate();
end;
```

Solution #2

```
type
  TAdder = class
  private
  _terms: array[1..10] of OleVariant;
    procedure _setTerm(i: Integer; const Value: OleVariant);
    function _getTerm(Index: Integer): OleVariant;

public
  property Terms[aIndex: Integer]: OleVariant read _getTerm write _SetTerm;
end;


function TAdder._getTerm(Index: Integer): OleVariant;
begin
  Result := _terms[Index];
end;

procedure TAdder._setTerm(i: Integer; const Value: OleVariant);
begin
  _terms[i] := TVarConv.NullableFloat(Value);
  _calculate();
end;
```

You might want to check if i is not out of range in _SetTerm and _GetTerm

Comment: Wow! Solution 1 matches my needs perfectly! Thank you. I didn't know about `index`.

Comment: @Paul I recomend you check documentation or some tutorials on `Indexed properties` to learn more about this topic. I bet knowledge on indexed properties will come in handy to you again in the future.

Comment: SilverWarior: I use indexed properties for years. I just didn't know that a static index could be used. I am using RTTI and do not want to mess with normal indexed properties this time.